# Partially delete path in zsh (Option + Backspace)

Tags: terminal, zsh

In zsh Option + Backspace deletes the whole path on a prompt. For example:

```
ls /usr/local/bin
```

Option + Backspace returns:

```
ls
```

How can I set the same behavior so that the shortcut deletes just one word, till the next delimiter, like:

```
ls /usr/local/bin
```

Option + Backspace should return:

```
ls /usr/local/
```

Comment: This seems to be related how zsh treats a word. Not sure how to change the behavior yet. If anyone knows please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An arbitrary number of alphabetic characters and digits **as well as** chars defined by WORDCHARS are considered all one *word* in zsh.

The default value of WORDCHARS is:

```
% echo $WORDCHARS
*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>
```

By defining another/a new WORDCHARS in .zprofile (and/or .zshrc|... - depends on how you configured your zsh environment), you can modify the behaviour of *werase (word erase - usually <kbd>ctrl/^</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>)*.

Simply add the line `export WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'` in .zprofile|..., close the Terminal window or `source .zprofile|...` and *werase*  works as you want afterwards.

Keep in mind that other shortcuts (like <kbd>alt/⌥</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>) will also be affected then.

---

If you want a different behaviour, check this question & answer: [zsh: using different WORDCHARS for kill-word and forward-word / backward-word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537178/zsh-using-different-wordchars-for-kill-word-and-forward-word-backward-word)

Comment: That's exactly what I end up doing but forgot to answer my question. Thank you.